# Flattening a numpy array with indexes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given a NumPy array of shape `(X, Y, 2)` representing an array of "frames" including "points" and every point having an `(x,y)` coordinate, I'd like to consolidate the first and second dimensions to an `(X*Y, 4)` array that now represents all of the points, and indexes of the X and Y dimensions.

For example, If my array is:

```
[
  [          # Frame 0
   [1, 2],   # Point 0
   [2, 3]    # Point 1
  ],
  [          # Frame 1
   [4, 5],   # Point 0
   [6, 7]    # Point 1
  ]
]
```

I'd like to get the array:

```
[
  [0, 0, 1, 2],   # Frame 0, Point 0
  [0, 1, 2, 3]    # Frame 0, Point 1
  [1, 0, 4, 5],   # Frame 1, Point 0
  [1, 1, 6, 7]    # Frame 1, Point 1
]
```

Slow solution:

```py
arr = np.array([[[1, 2],[2, 3]],[[4, 5],[6, 7]]])
new_arr = []
for i, points in enumerate(arr):
  for j, point in enumerate(points):
    new_arr.append([i, j] + point.tolist())
```

Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve each part separately using [numpy.ndindex](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.ndindex.html) to get indices and `.reshape()`. Then you can use [numpy.c_](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html) to stack them.

```
a = np.array([[[1, 2],[2, 3]],[[4, 5],[6, 7]]])
c = a.reshape(-1, a.shape[-1])
print(c)
# [[1 2]
#  [2 3]
#  [4 5]
#  [6 7]]
indices = list(np.ndindex(a.shape[:-1]))
print(indices)
# [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
print(np.c_[indices, c])
# [[0 0 1 2]
#  [0 1 2 3]
#  [1 0 4 5]
#  [1 1 6 7]]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the simplest solution, and it scales to more index dimensions

Comment: Yes, much more general than my solution.

Comment: Just tested it with higher dimensionality and can confirm that it works.

Answer (score 1):

A larger example array is used in this code so that it could be tested with different sizes in each dimension:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array(
    [
        [          
            [1, 2],   
            [2, 3],   
            [3, 4]    
            ],
        [          
            [4, 5],   
            [6, 7],    
            [8, 7]    
            ],
        [          
            [14, 5],   
            [16, 7],    
            [18, 7]    
            ],
        [            
            [24, 5],   
            [26, 7],    
            [28, 7]    
            ]
        ]
)

x, y = arr.shape[:2]
assert(arr.shape[2] == 2)
ay, ax = (a.reshape(x, y, 1) for a in np.meshgrid(np.arange(y), np.arange(x)))
new_array = np.concatenate([ax, ay, arr], axis=2).reshape(x * y, 4)

print(repr(new_array))
```

gives the following:

```
array([[ 0,  0,  1,  2],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 0,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 1,  0,  4,  5],
       [ 1,  1,  6,  7],
       [ 1,  2,  8,  7],
       [ 2,  0, 14,  5],
       [ 2,  1, 16,  7],
       [ 2,  2, 18,  7],
       [ 3,  0, 24,  5],
       [ 3,  1, 26,  7],
       [ 3,  2, 28,  7]])
```

And using your original example array gives:

```
array([[0, 0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [1, 0, 4, 5],
       [1, 1, 6, 7]])
```

There are no explicit loops, so it ought to be faster. (Any looping is inside numpy and will be implemented in optimised C code.)

Comment: Thank you, this is really fast. Any way to extend it to more indexes? what if there was another dimension to index `(X,Y,Z,2)` ?

Comment: @Amit I didn't consider that case because you didn't request it, and given that I used `meshgrid`, it is probably not straightforwardly extended to do this. (By the way, I just edited it to use the same variable name `arr`, so you might want to grab a fresh copy.)

Comment: @Amit You might want to look at the other answer (V.Ayrat). I've not looked at it in detail, but it looks really generic regarding the number of dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new to NumPy but I think this should work (someone correct me if I'm wrong): arr.reshape(-1,4)

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: `reshape` just moves the data inside the array, and doesn't relate to indexes